# AT-COMMAND how to check data connection

Tags: at-command, gprs, sim-card, ppp

I seek for a full proof method to check if the modem is connected to data network ?

As I have seen, there is two differents commands :

1. at+cgreg : Give GPRS status
2. at+creg : Give GSM / UMTS status

In some case (maybe one time on ten), I get the following result :

```
at+creg?
+CREG: 2,5,"00CA","007993E2",2
```

and

```
at+cgreg?
+CGREG: 2,3
```

So the GSM is configured in UMTS, but the GPRS cannot be registered. Can I considere that the data network can be used without GPRS (from UMTS) ?

Comment: What is your modem model?

Comment: I use Sierra HL8548 - HL 8548-G - HL7690

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At commands finishing with "reg" are related to network registration. To check if the modem is attached to the packet switched (data) domain you can use at+cgatt? command.
Further, if you want to check if the PDP context or bearer is activated you can use at+cgact? command. Of course you need both to be activated in order to send and receive data to and from Internet.

Comment: Does the Ct+cgact correct, I think the command is At+cgact. But thanks for the information, I will include this change in my software.

Comment: SUre you're right, that was a typing mistake that I already corrected!